# Simple Reactjs app without using npm and server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a simple Reactjs app without using npm and server.py, server.js etc. I just want to run my index.html in a browser. Currently what I am getting is nothing will get rendered and browser shows blank white screen, there are no errors in console as well. I have included the following scripts.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.3284-6/12350972_1539644969670605_801198237_n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t39.3284-6/12056978_1723186904561917_1347349243_n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here `app.js` is my js which renders certain components into DOM.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

This is my `app.js`

**Update**

Now I am getting this error message

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You should include `app.js` here too - it's hard to figure out what the problem is if we can't see your code.

Comment: Also, look out for errors in the console

Comment: I'm sure that whatever your trying to render will have to be done on FireFox as Chrome's XSS is extremely strict. Running all of this stuff on a localhost server is one way to bypass all of the non-sense.

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: Can you paste all of your HTML, too?  It happened to me at least once that I had forgotten to add <div id="container"></div> in the HTML.

Comment: If I write script in same index.html it works fine but when I try to include script from my `app.js` nothing gets rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this instructions and starter kit might be useful for you: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the react jsx which isn't being processed with babel on the fly. Removing the JSX works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/zevndLog/

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'MyComponent',

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      'Hello'
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyComponent, null), document.getElementById('container'));
```

Can't remember off the top of my mind if / how you tell babel to compile jsx on the fly